# Huge static (mysql) database in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am developing an application and try to implement the microservice architecture. For information about locations (cities, zip codes, etc.) I downloaded a database dump for mysql from opengeodb.org.

Now I want to provide the database as a docker container.
I set up a mysql image with following Dockerfile as mentioned in the docs for the mysql image:

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE geodb
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD ${PWD}/sql .
EXPOSE 3306
```

The "sql"-folder contains sql scripts with the raw data as insert statements, so it creates the whole database.The problem is, that the database is really huge and it takes really long to set it up.

So I thought, maybe there is a possibility to save the created database inside an image, because it is an static database for read-only operations only.

I am fairly new to docker and not quite sure how to achieve this.

I'm using docker on a Windows 10 machine.

EDIT: 
I achieved my goal by doing the following:

1. I added the sql dump file as described above.
2. I ran the container and built the whole database with a local directory (the 'data' folder) mounted to /var/lib/mysql.
3. Then stopped the container and edited the Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM mysql
   ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
   ENV MYSQL_DATABASE geodb
   WORKDIR /var/lib/mysql
   COPY ${PWD}\data .
   EXPOSE 3306
   ```

   So the generated Database is now beeing copied from local system into the container.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a volume with your container to persist the database on your local machine. When you first create the container, the SQL in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will be executed, and the changes will be stored to the volume. Next time you start the container, MySQL will see that the schema already exists and it won't run the scripts again.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: So I could first let it create the database from the dump file, storing it in my mounted folder and then after the creation has finished just ADD the files within the Dockerfile, so it never has to recreate the database...

Comment: No, you don't need to mount a folder. Just create a named volume (with the `-v` flag) when you create your container, and ADD the files as usual.

Comment: Okay I understand. I thought of a portable image of the whole database, so when i run the image on any other machine it has the whole database ready. When i'm using the -v flag the database is only stored inside docker on my machine. Please correct me, if i'm wrong. :-)

Comment: @Ragnar you're right. However, you can transfer volumes to other machines - the process isn't straightforward, but it can be done (although I never have, so I can't help you there)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you could achieve it like this:

1. start the container
2. load the database
3. perform  a `docker commit` to build an image of the current state of the container.

The other option would be to load in the database during the image build time, but for this you would have to start mysql similarly to how it's done in the [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/696fc899126ae00771b5d87bdadae836e704ae7d/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) script.

1. start mysql in background
2. wait for it to initialize
3. load in the data using `mysql < sql file`